# How to wire to control motors with Raspberry Pi ZERO

Tags: pi-zero-w

How do I wire the cable to control the motor with the Raspberry Pi ZERO using the [28BYJ-48](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/758/stepd-01-data-sheet-1143075.pdf) and the [Adafruit TB6612 1.2A DC/stepping motor driver](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2448)?

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tb6612-h-bridge-dc-stepper-motor-driver-breakout/python-circuitpython

I have tried the above page and many other ways to control the motor.

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the edit you made is a very good step in improving your post ... now add a description of what you actually did, and what the results were ... maybe we can figure out where the problem lies ... `have tried the above page and many other ways to control the motor.` is not a useful description of what actually happened

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Just refer to one of the hundreds of online tutorials.

If you have a problem explain what you have done (software and wiring) and what is not working as expected.

Comment: Do you know how to cable and control the motor. Please tell us.

Comment: As I said.  There are hundreds of tutorials.  Do the required research.  This is not a do my homework site.